# Concatenation of the dataframes and use of axis parameter in pandas concat function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two dataframes using pandas `concat` function. When I use the function without the `axis` parameter, I get `NaN` values in the concatenated dataframe.

```
hr_data_core = pd.DataFrame([[6368264,41,'Female'],
                             [6589733,49,'Male'],
                             [6921082,37,'Male'],
                             [8516310,33,'Female'],
                             [2305936,27,'Male']],
                            columns=['e_id','Age','Gender'])
hr_data = pd.DataFrame([[6368264,'Yes',94],
                        [6589733,'No',61],
                        [6921082,'Yes',92],
                        [8516310,'No',56],
                        [2305936,'No',40]],
                        columns=['e_id','Attrition','HourlyRate'])
hr_data_all = pd.concat([hr_data_core,hr_data.drop(columns='e_id')])
hr_data_all.head()
```

Can anyone explain why I get `NaN` values when I do not use the `axis` parameter in `concat` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`axis` determines to concatenate along which axis, which is `0` for row-wise and `1` for column-wise.

So its default value is `0` and the `hr_data` columns `Attrition,HourlyRate` look for these two columns in `hr_data_core`, and not found, so blank NaN column added.

But if you add `axis=1`, then the concatenation is column-wise, so two successfully concatenate.

Comment: My issue is when I use axis=1 the rows in the 2nd dataframe flip upside down, I have used the sort=False argument as well and for the life of me, I cannot get the data to just join without flipping, it's driving me crazy